# Can't control the view function

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I am having a problem on my viewing function in my desktop application.
The program lets the user view the names and corresponding details by clicking the "view all" button.
The problem is if the user clicks the "View all" button again it will add another set of the list stored in the database.

This is what happened after the second click

[image]

Can you help me stop this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the `JTextArea` in the View All button's actionhandler. Use the `setText(String s)` method to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not formatted in a legible manner. It would probably be better to use a JTable to display the data. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information and working examples.

When you are ready to refresh the data you create a new TableModel with the updated data. Then you update the table with the new data by using:

```
table.setModel( yourNewModel );
```